# calling a function with dynamic objectname pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Sorry of the above statement of the question isn't clear I don't know exactly how to frame it.

My query is I have some buttons which have same functionality but they are repeated Hence i want to redice the code so i want to call the function with object name and get values / do any operation on that object

Here is a sample code.

```
self.movement('intro_files_paths',final_intro_list)
```

movement is a function that I want to call for a particular functionality
intro_files_paths is the object name of pyqt5 item Widget

and the function of movement is like this

```
def movement(self,b,c):

    index=self.b.currentRow()

    c=self.swapPositions(c,index,index-1)

    self.b.clear()

    for i in c:
        self.b.addItem(i)
```

so here im getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'UI' object has no attribute 'b'
```

i did understand why im getting the error
But no idea how to resolve this issue

more info:
I'm building a video editing application where I'm trying to do bulk video editing. Hence when some one opens a file that file names are stored in a list and show in the qt list widget in the order they opened them so after opening them a user might want to change the order of the videos hence to do this I gave move_up move_down and delete_item

everything below is in the same class

**Full code**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys

final_intro_list= ['C:/Users/thota/OneDrive/Desktop/VET/testing area/1.mp4', 'C:/Users/thota/OneDrive/Desktop/VET/testing area/2.mp4', 'C:/Users/thota/OneDrive/Desktop/VET/testing area/30sec.mp4', 'C:/Users/thota/OneDrive/Desktop/VET/testing area/1280.mp4', 'C:/Users/thota/OneDrive/Desktop/VET/testing area/12800.mp4', 'C:/Users/thota/OneDrive/Desktop/VET/testing area/out.mp4', 'C:/Users/thota/OneDrive/Desktop/VET/testing area/output.mp4']

class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("lol.ui", self)

        self.show()

        self.move_up_4.clicked.connect(self.move_up_in_list_4)
        self.move_down_4.clicked.connect(self.move_down_in_list_4)
        self.remove_4.clicked.connect(self.remove_in_list_4)
        for i in final_intro_list:
            self.intro_files_paths.addItem(i)

    def move_up_in_list_4(self):
        global final_intro_list
        self.movement(0,'intro_files_paths',final_intro_list)

    def move_down_in_list_4(self):
        global final_intro_list
        self.movement(1,'intro_files_paths',final_intro_list)

    def remove_in_list_4(self):
        global final_intro_list
        self.movement(2,'intro_files_paths',final_intro_list)

    def movement(self,a,b,c):
        index=self.b.currentRow()
        if(a==0): #moving up in list
            c=self.swapPositions(c,index,index-1)
        elif(a==1): #moving down in list
            c=self.swapPositions(c,index,index+1)
        else: # delete that item
            del c[index]
        self.b.clear()
        for i in c:
            self.b.addItem(i)

    def swapPositions(self,list, pos1, pos2):
         list[pos1], list[pos2] = list[pos2], list[pos1]
         return list


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = UI()
app.exec_()
```

[image]

GUI code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>811</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QListWidget" name="intro_files_paths">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>100</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>430</width>
      <height>290</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="dragDropMode">
     <enum>QAbstractItemView::DragDrop</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="movement">
     <enum>QListView::Free</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="spacing">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="gridSize">
     <size>
      <width>20</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="viewMode">
     <enum>QListView::ListMode</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="remove_4">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>540</x>
      <y>270</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset>
      <normaloff>Cross.png</normaloff>Cross.png</iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="iconSize">
     <size>
      <width>50</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="move_up_4">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>540</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset>
      <normaloff>up.png</normaloff>up.png</iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="iconSize">
     <size>
      <width>50</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="move_down_4">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>540</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset>
      <normaloff>down.png</normaloff>down.png</iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="iconSize">
     <size>
      <width>50</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: b should not have a self attribute. it is an argument passed in to ur method. therefore you cant access that way

Comment: yes i understood the issue but how can i resolve it to achieve the requirement

Comment: Using object names (or instance attributes) is rarely required, and it's often a requirement caused by bad implementation. What function is going to call `self.movement`? Why can't you just pass the reference of the widget instead? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: sorry for that i have added the code please check it once

Comment: Are `movement()` and `move_up_in_list_4()` in a class? We usually use the argument `self` only for class methods in python. If these are global methods, I suggest that you give the parameter a more descriptive name to describe what it is. Similarly, `b` and `c` should be renamed to be more descriptive.

Comment: yes they all belong to the same class "movement() and move_up_in_list_4()"

Comment: @musicamante I have updated the code in the post please check it once sorry for tagging  thank you

Comment: @EswarT I didn't ask you to provide "more info", I specifically requested you to provide a MRE (please, read that link and follow its instructions), we must be able to understand exactly what you're doing and possibly be also able to copy, paste and run your code with minimal modifications. Right now it's absolutely unclear what you're doing, also due to the confusing way you're indenting (and we cannot correctly understand and debug code if the indentation is wrong).

Comment: @musicamante sorry for that sir I have added the GUI image and code and some image so u can get more info about it to thank you

Comment: @musicamante I do know that I can repeat the code and achieve it directly but I do know keeping code clean so I thought of calling so I'm confused about how to make that b to be recognized as the passed object name thank you sir

Comment: @EswarT does that seem code we can copy, paste and run?

Comment: @musicamante sir added GUI as an image and the code which is runnable

Comment: @musicamante sir Added full working code with GUI code also tested it so u can test directly getting same error "AttributeError: 'UI' object has no attribute 'b'" sorry and Thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `movement` function you have a `b` argument, but you're trying to access `self.b`. The error is pretty clear: there's no `b` object in your UI, nor in your instance, but even if it were, it doesn't make a lot of sense, since you want to use the argument of the function.

Since those functions already refer to actual objects, there's really no point in trying to access the attributes as strings, just use the attribute:

```
    def remove_in_list_4(self):
        global final_intro_list
        self.movement(2, self.intro_files_paths, final_intro_list)

    def movement(self, a, b, c):
        index = b.currentRow()
```

Just for the sake of knowledge, you *can* use string literals to access instance attributes:

```
        # ...
        self.movement(2, 'intro_files_paths', final_intro_list)

    def movement(self, a, b, c):
        index = getattr(self, b).currentRow()
```

And the same for Qt objects:

```
    def movement(self, a, b, c):
        index = self.findChild(QListWidget, b).currentRow()
```

But, as said, using name attributes should only be done in specific situations (for instance, objects created dynamically as consequence of configuration file parsing). For any other situations, it's usually not required, and it generally is symptom of a bad implementation.

In any case, I strongly suggest you to do some more research and studying on classes and instances (what they are, how they work), and seriously improve your syntax and naming: having variables named "a, b, c" is meaningless, it doesn't provide any benefits and makes your code only more difficult to read (even to you); read more about the suggested practice on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
Finally, using globals is always discouraged; the rule of thumb is: you should only use them if you really know why they should be used, and if you know why they should be used, then you will probably not use them. Use instance attributes instead.

Comment: Thanks sir, Got when I'm doing it wrong and now i understood how to post a query will follow this and sorry if i wasted some of ur time by commenting again and again thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `self.b`, do just `self` or `b` because these are the parameters to the function. Which one you use depends on which object you are operating on.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `b` in the function whereas you're using `self.b` in the function.